# different colours and customizations for individual vertices/nodes for a tikz graph

Tags: color, diagrams, graphs, tikz-pic

So I draw my graphs like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=black,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
            \node[Bullet,label=left :{$u_1$}] (u1) at (0,2){};
            \node[Bullet,label=above:{$u_2$}] (u2) at (1,3){};
            \node[Bullet,label=right:{$u_3$}] (u3) at (2,2){};
            \node[Bullet,label=right:{$u_4$}] (u4) at (2,0){};
            \node[Bullet,label=left :{$u_5$}] (u5) at (0,0){};
            \draw[thick] (u1)--(u4)--(u5)--(u3)--(u2)--(u1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to set individual colours for each of the nodes/vertices. And I can, but it seems a bit clunky.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=red,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
            \node[Bullet,label=left :{$u_1$}] (u1) at (0,2){};
            \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=orange,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
            \node[Bullet,label=above:{$u_2$}] (u2) at (1,3){};
            \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=yellow,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
            \node[Bullet,label=right:{$u_3$}] (u3) at (2,2){};
            \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=green,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
            \node[Bullet,label=right:{$u_4$}] (u4) at (2,0){};
            \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=blue,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
            \node[Bullet,label=left :{$u_5$}] (u5) at (0,0){};
            \draw[thick] (u1)--(u4)--(u5)--(u3)--(u2)--(u1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I'd really like is to be able to get it looking like this, to highlight isomorphisms:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can set the style with parameter `Bullet/.style={fill=#1,...}` and then use it as `Bullet=<color>`. And you should also remove `color=black` which set the color of `fill`, `draw` and `text` to `black`.

Comment: Hey, I just want to request this be reopened to allow answers. Reason being, the linked answer is not quite the answer I was hoping for. For instance the colours used aren't standard colours, and they have to be defined in the preamble. I've learnt how to do it in the meantime, but it's not just for me. also there are other customizations like the position of the labels centred directly on the nodes/vertices, etc. I think it's worth letting people submit new answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your point of reopening this question. The linked question (or Kpym's comment) does *exactly* what you want to get.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill=black,draw,color=#1,circle,minimum size=3pt,scale=0.75}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[Bullet=red,label=left :{$u_1$}] (u1) at (0,2){};
    \node[Bullet=orange,label=above:{$u_2$}] (u2) at (1,3){};
    \node[Bullet=yellow,label=right:{$u_3$}] (u3) at (2,2){};
    \node[Bullet=green,label=right:{$u_4$}] (u4) at (2,0){};
    \node[Bullet=blue,label=left :{$u_5$}] (u5) at (0,0){};
    \draw[thick] (u1)--(u4)--(u5)--(u3)--(u2)--(u1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]